# How to create an android table dynamically by reusing one layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, indexoutofboundsexception, android-tablelayout

I am making a app to display the content of a small database as a dynamically created table. I use an init() function to create the table onCreate and want it to be then filled with the data. Since the first or caption row is static, I decided to hardcode that one and then create the rest with a loop through the database. Problem is it does throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to run it. I assume it has something to do with the removeView() calls I use to recycle my layout, but really not sure. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

The init function:

```
//Initiates the table
public void init(){

    //This part defines the layout to be used for creating new rows
    TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    TextView tdate = new TextView(this);
    TextView tweight = new TextView(this);

    //This generates the caption row
    tdate.setText("Weight");
    tdate.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    tweight.setText("Date");
    tweight.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    row.addView(tdate);
    row.addView(tweight);
    ll.addView(row,0);

    //This loop adds the database content to the table (using hardcoded values here for demonstration)
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        ((ViewGroup)tdate.getParent()).removeView(tdate);
        ((ViewGroup)tweight.getParent()).removeView(tweight);
        ((ViewGroup)row.getParent()).removeView(row);

        tdate.setText("20.20.2020");
        tdate.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        tweight.setText("89");
        tweight.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        row.addView(tdate);
        row.addView(tweight);
        ll.addView(row,i);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
07-03 11:00:34.903  30276-30276/net.sanctum.adhominem.sanctum E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: net.sanctum.adhominem.sanctum, PID: 30276
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.sanctum.adhominem.sanctum/net.sanctum.adhominem.sanctum.Log}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3902)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3733)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3678)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
        at net.sanctum.adhominem.sanctum.Log.init(Log.java:77)
        at net.sanctum.adhominem.sanctum.Log.onCreate(Log.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
```

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: It says line 77 of the init() function is the problem. Looking over the code it looks like you only ever create one row in the table. This would explain why it is saying out of bounds when you try to access a second row (at position 1). If the table is always hard coded you could put all the rows in the xml with different ids/vales in each position. If you want data to vary a ListView with an Adapter may be more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,

```
//Initiates the table
public void init(){

    //This part defines the layout to be used for creating new rows
    TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
    TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    TextView tdate = new TextView(this);
    TextView tweight = new TextView(this);

    //This generates the caption row
    tdate.setText("Weight");
    tdate.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    tweight.setText("Date");
    tweight.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    row.addView(tdate);
    row.addView(tweight);
    ll.addView(row,0);

    //This loop adds the database content to the table (using hardcoded values here for demonstration)
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {

        row= new TableRow(this);
        lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tdate = new TextView(this);
        tweight = new TextView(this);
        tdate.setText("20.20.2020");
        tdate.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        tweight.setText("89");
        tweight.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        row.addView(tdate);
        row.addView(tweight);
        ll.addView(row,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. What was my mistake here? Would really help me avoiding that in the future.

Comment: you are adding row into table layout and then removed from layout (everytime it has child count 0 but you are giving 1,2,3)that's why it is showing AIOE.

Comment: if you adding the same row into the layout in loop then it shows as view already exists please remove, so need to create every time a new table row while adding to layout.